# Angularjs do something if screen width is less than 800 px

Tags: angularjs

How can I make Angularjs to do something if my screen width is less than 800 pixels? my similar jquery code

```
if (screen.width < 800) {
alert('Less than 800');
}
else {

alert('More than 800');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of directive that will watch the window size. Shortly: use $watch and $window.width()

```
app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
return function (scope, element) {
    var w = angular.element($window);
    scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
        return {
            'h': w.height(),
            'w': w.width()
        };
    };
    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
        scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

        scope.style = function () {
            return {
                'height': (newValue.h - 100) + 'px',
                    'width': (newValue.w - 100) + 'px'
            };
        };

    }, true);

    w.bind('resize', function () {
        scope.$apply();
    });
  }
})
```